# Conditional pausing in Matlab (not Debugging)

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab so please bear with me.

So I created a two GUID GUI in which one generates a dynamic data and updates the plotting every second so I used `pause(1)` (which is continuous) and the second one takes the full data of the first GUI and plots it (opens on button press)

Is there a way where if I open the the second GUI the first GUI pauses and if and only if the second GUI is stopped the first GUI resumes its process?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Example:

gui1.m

```
function guie1()
   for ii=1:100
    c = magic(ii)
    plot(c);
    % a button at this point
    % Some pause condition
    drawnow;   
   end
```

so when I click on that button it would open a window (a new figure may be) so unless I close is the loop should be paused.

Comment: that sounds a bit convoluted and the dependency between the GUIs is not very clear. It would be better if you could provide a minimal example of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
run(fullfile(docroot,'techdoc','creating_guis','examples','callback_interrupt'));
```

Here is the link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/callback-sequencing-and-interruption.html

**Update:**

Here:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/03/how-to-loop-until-a-button-is-pushed-in-matlab/

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29618-spspj

Comment: hey this is not what I am looking for. Please have a look at the updated question.